# Hibernate Joins using HQL

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

I just need a simple example in HQL (no Criteria) where I have two tables which need to be joined with left outer join on a column which is of type 'int'. I have Sybase at the back-end.

I have looked into a lot places(even on this site) and including [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) but didn't find them too useful for first time users.

Consider I have Table 'First' and Table 'Second' with the join column 'empID' as 'int'. How can I left outer join First with second using a named query.
Please also specify if any additional mapping changes are required to the hbm files of First and Second class. I am sure it will help simplify joins for a lot of Hibernate newbies.

EDIT:

empID is a value which is definitely present in table First and may or may not be present in table Second. It just refers to an employee.

Comment: is there a relationship between 'First' and 'Second' or do they just happen to both reference an employee?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Joins are only possible if there is an association between two entities.

You could be able to do what you want if you had:

- a ManyToOne or OneToOne association from First to Employee
- a OneToMany or OneToOne association from Employee to Second

and in this case, the query would look like

```
select first from First first
inner join fetch first.employee employee
left join fetch employee.second(s) second
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ... from First as f, Second as s where f.employee.Id = s.employee.Id
```